# Swift 3: Understand syntax change for UITableViewDataSource method

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have some questions with Swift 3 function calling. Below is an example.

Old Swift:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell
```

Swift 3:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

That's fine with the above syntax. But now Xcode shows me an error and asks me to do like below:

```
@objc(tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

I do not understand why I have to declare `@objc(tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`.

This is happening only when I am trying to implement table view datasource methods under an extension. Also this is not happening for `numberOfRowsInSection` or `viewForHeaderInSection`.

Can anyone help me to understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure what triggers the `@objc`, I can suggest the following approach:

Store the tableView variable somewhere in the viewDidLoad:

```
let tv = tableView!
```

Then hover over the tableView variable and press the command button in conjunction with a click.

**This should take you to the interface of a UITableView**.

Then, hover over either UITableViewDelegate or UITableViewDataSource and press the command button in conjunction with a click.

Now you can see the new signatures.

A lot has changed...Happy upgrade!

Answer (score 0):

Swift compiler forced to write Objc(funcName) before function if you are using this function from Objective c. According to app doc

> Use the @objc(name) attribute to provide Objective-C names for
>   properties and methods when necessary. For example, you can mark a
>   property called enabled to have a getter named isEnabled in
>   Objective-C like this:

```
    var enabled: Bool {
    @objc(isEnabled) get {
        // ...
      }
   }
```

- To void this, use extension to write TableView Datasource and delegate

> ```
>  extension YourViewControllerName:UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
>
>     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
>     {
>         return 10
>     }
>
>     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
>
>         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell() as SplitAddContactCell
>         return cell
>     }
>
>     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
>         return 80.0
>     }
>
> }
> ```